# Using rollup for both strings and numbers

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm working with the following dataset:

```
Landen,"Perioden","SITC","Onderwerpen_1","Waarde eenheid","Waarde"
Afghanistan,"2012","0 Voeding en levende dieren","Invoerwaarde","mln euro","1"
Afghanistan,"2012","1 Dranken en tabak","Invoerwaarde","mln euro","0"
Afghanistan,"2012","2 Grondstoffen niet eetbaar behalve...","Invoerwaarde","mln euro","."
Afghanistan,"2012","3 Minerale brandstoffen smeermiddele...","Invoerwaarde","mln euro","."
Afghanistan,"2012","4 Dierlijke en plantaardige oliën en ...","Invoerwaarde","mln euro","."
Afghanistan,"2012","5 Chemische producten","Invoerwaarde","mln euro","0"
Afghanistan,"2012","6 Fabricaten hoofdzakelijk gerangschi...","Invoerwaarde","mln euro","0"
Afghanistan,"2012","7 Machines en vervoermaterieel","Invoerwaarde","mln euro","1"
Afghanistan,"2012","8 Diverse gefabriceerde goederen","Invoerwaarde","mln euro","1"
Afghanistan,"2012","9 Niet afzonderlijk genoemde goederen","Invoerwaarde","mln euro","0"
```

The first thing I do is change all the 'Waarde' values that aren't "." into integers like so:

```
for (let i = 0; i < dataTotal.length; i++) {
    if (dataTotal[i].Waarde != ".") {
        dataTotal[i].Waarde = parseInt(dataTotal[i].Waarde);
    }
}
```

Then I use d3.nest to make a new more usable array as follows:

```
nested_data = d3.nest()
    .key(function (d) {
        return d.SITC;
    })
    .rollup(function (d) {
        return d3.sum(d, function (e) {
                return e.Waarde
        });
    });
    .entries(dataTotal);
```

The results is the following:

[image: img1]

As you can see the d3.sum changes the "." values to 0, which makes sense. However I would like the rollup to return a number when dataTotal.Waarde is a number, and return a string with "." when it's not. I tried the following:

```
nested_data = d3.nest()
    .key(function (d) {
        return d.SITC;
    })
    .rollup(function (d) {
        if (typeof dataTotal.Waarde == "number") {
            return d3.sum(d, function (e) {
                return e.Waarde
            });
        } else if (typeof dataTotal.Waarde == "string"){

        }
    })
    .entries(dataTotal);
```

This is the result:

[image: img2]

Now it returns undefined for all values. How can I solve this problem where I want the rollup to return numbers where dataTotal.Waarde is a number and return the string "." where it's not?

Comment: The rollup sums all the values for a give key. If the values are, for instance, `1`, `2`, and `3`,  the rollup returns `6`. But what if the values are `1`, `.` and `2`? What's the expected outcome?

Comment: In my script rollup doesn't sum up multiple values. I'm simply using it to put the data in a easily useable form, so your example wouldn't be a problem. Say it would be, the expected outcome would be ".".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55762323/using-rollup-for-both-strings-and-numbers?noredirect=1#comment98283037_55762323) you don't need `d3.nest()` at all! You can create that array you want with a simple [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), using an [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) to convert the string to a number and testing for `NaN` in the case of `"."`:

```
const nested = data.map(function(d) {
  return {
    key: d.SITC,
    value: +d.Waarde === +d.Waarde ? +d.Waarde : d.Waarde
  };
});
```

Here is a demo:

```js
const csv = `Landen,"Perioden","SITC","Onderwerpen_1","Waarde eenheid","Waarde"
Afghanistan,"2012","0 Voeding en levende dieren","Invoerwaarde","mln euro","1"
Afghanistan,"2012","1 Dranken en tabak","Invoerwaarde","mln euro","0"
Afghanistan,"2012","2 Grondstoffen niet eetbaar behalve...","Invoerwaarde","mln euro","."
Afghanistan,"2012","3 Minerale brandstoffen smeermiddele...","Invoerwaarde","mln euro","."
Afghanistan,"2012","4 Dierlijke en plantaardige oliën en ...","Invoerwaarde","mln euro","."
Afghanistan,"2012","5 Chemische producten","Invoerwaarde","mln euro","0"
Afghanistan,"2012","6 Fabricaten hoofdzakelijk gerangschi...","Invoerwaarde","mln euro","0"
Afghanistan,"2012","7 Machines en vervoermaterieel","Invoerwaarde","mln euro","1"
Afghanistan,"2012","8 Diverse gefabriceerde goederen","Invoerwaarde","mln euro","1"
Afghanistan,"2012","9 Niet afzonderlijk genoemde goederen","Invoerwaarde","mln euro","0"`;

const data = d3.csvParse(csv);

const nested = data.map(function(d) {
  return {
    key: d.SITC,
    value: +d.Waarde === +d.Waarde ? +d.Waarde : d.Waarde
  };
});

console.log(nested)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That makes it so much easier, thank you. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks so much!